# How to get all my feeds exclude which is commented by me

Tags: django, django-orm

there are three classes

```
class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class Feed(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Comment(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
```

If I specified a user named Jack, how to get Jack's feeds and comments of them, but not get the comments which the user of the comment if not Jack

If there are two feeds of Jack:

```
[
  "feed1": [{"comment1": {"user": "Lily"}}, {"comment2": {"user": "Bruce"}],
  "feed2": [{"comment1": {"user": "Jack"}}, {"comment2": {"user":"Lily"}],
]
```

I use the follow code to get:

```
Feed.objects.filter(user__name="Jack").exclude(comment__user__name="Jack")
```

I want to get the result:

```
[
  "feed1": [{"comment1": {"user": "Lily"}}, {"comment2": {"user": "Bruce"}],
  "feed2": [{"comment2": {"user":"Lily"}],
]
```

but in fact, it returns the wrong result:

```
[
  "feed1": [{"comment1": {"user": "Lily"}}, {"comment2": {"user": "Bruce"}]
]
```

I just want remove the comment which is not commented by Jack, but it remove all the feed which one of its comment has the same user Jack

Comment: Firstly you should retrieve all the feeds of the user and after that, you can retrieve all the comments on each feed excluding the comment posted by jack

Comment: Is it the only way??? you take two times connecting the sql

Comment: You can optimize it using prefetch_related. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: I don't know if this is the only way. Maybe other developers have different approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefetch all the comments excluding comments from jack

```
feeds = Feed.objects.filter(user__name="Jack").prefetch_related(
Prefetch(
"feed_set",
queryset="comment.objects.exclude(user__name='Jack')",
to_attr='all_comments'
)
```

You can get the comments for each feed by

```
for feed in feeds:
    comments = feed.all_comments #No database call is made by this statement
```

Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related to learn more about prefetch_related.

Comment: you are grate!!! you solve my problem which is hard to me!!! thank you very much!!!

Comment: I am happy to help you.